# Add multiple images

Tags: flutter

I want display multiple Containers with images but I don't want fill the code with Containers, I want do some validations to displaying them. What is the best way to do this?

```
Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child:Image.asset("images/a.png"),//if validation ok show this1              
),
Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child:Image.asset("images/b.png"),//if validation ok show this1              
        )
Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child:Image.asset("images/c.png"),//if validation ok show this1              
        )
//d.png e.png f.png g.png...
```

Im new at Dart, I just need a tip. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by Image childs? Containers that have Image.asset? You may use function that returns List<Widget>

Comment: yes sir, containers that have Image.asset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You may try this tip :

**define ImageCard once**

```dart
class ImageCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  ImageCard({this.imagePath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return imagePath != null // null handler
        ? Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Image.asset(imagePath),
          )
        : Container();
  }
}
```

**render multiple images programmatically at screen widget**

```dart
List<Widget> renderImages(){  
   List<Widget> renderImages() {
    var temp = <Widget>[];
    for (var imagePath in imagePaths) {

      // add some conditional logic here
      // we only add more Item if it matches certain condition

      if (imagePath.contains('3') || imagePath.contains('5')) {
        temp.add(ImageCard(
          imagePath: imagePath,
        ));
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    ...
    child: Column(
      children: renderImages(),
    ),
    ...
}
```

#### Full-code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> imagePaths = [
  "assets/images/flower-1.jpeg",
  "assets/images/flower-2.jpeg",
  "assets/images/flower-3.jpeg",
  "assets/images/flower-4.jpeg",
  "assets/images/flower-5.jpeg",
];

class ImageCardScreenEfficient extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Widget> renderImages() {
    var temp = <Widget>[];
    for (var imagePath in imagePaths) {
      // add some conditional logic here
      if (imagePath.contains('3') || imagePath.contains('5')) {
        temp.add(ImageCard(
          imagePath: imagePath,
        ));
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Image Cards Efficient "),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: renderImages(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  ImageCard({this.imagePath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Image.asset(imagePath),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Repository

You may look into this repo [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout)

#### Demo

[image: demo]

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but it seems to be what I need! Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Sir the image paths are ok but i still have this error: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4568): The following assertion was thrown building ImageCard(dirty):
I/flutter ( 4568): 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart': Failed assertion: line 134 pos 15: 'assetName
I/flutter ( 4568): != null': is not true.

Comment: probably at the business logic, the app still consider imagePath which contains null. Please check its iteration on this part  `for (var imagePath in imagePaths) `

Comment: I'm trying a few things without success

Comment: okay please try to change ImageCard definition as updated code above. Note that I already put some null handler, to prevent Image.asset being called if the path is null

Comment: Very good sir! Thank you. Could you send me any documentation to understand better the way how widgets can be used like this?

Comment: in my early days, this article helps me a lot. https://iirokrankka.com/2018/06/18/putting-build-methods-on-a-diet/#problem-4---bracket-hell . After that section, go to this article https://iirokrankka.com/2018/12/11/splitting-widgets-to-methods-performance-antipattern/ . Hope it helps

Comment: I faced this issue `'package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart': Failed assertion: line 134 pos 15: 'assetName != null': is not true.` because image path value was null.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function that returns a list of widgets

```
List<Widget> createWidget(bool isTrueValidation){
    var images = ["images/a.png","images/b.png","images/c.png"];
    List<Widget> list = List<Widget>();

    for(var i in images){
        list.add(
            isTrueValidation ?
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child:Image.asset(images[i])             
            ) : Container()
        );
    }
}
```